# HTML code generates tags by itself

Tags: jquery, html, css

When I open my file in Firefox or any browser it places an `<a>` tag inside my code. 
As soon as I run the file the link tag appears right under my **navbar** section. In some cases it even surrounds my whole content.

Can the link tags be suppressed from a code standpoint?

EDIT: I've made some research. Deactivated JavaScript and CSS, still the same problem. But when I downloaded my HTML from the browser i noticed the following lines:

```html
 <div class="row">
                    <ul class="list-inline pull-right nofloat-m text-center">
                        <li>
                            <a href="">
                                <img class="img-responsive inline-block socialmedia" src="./Machimaris Werbung - Folienshop Bonn_files/fb.gif" alt="Facebook" <="" a="">
                        </a></li><a href="">
                        </a><li><a href="">
                            </a><a href="">
                                <img class="img-responsive inline-block socialmedia" src="./Machimaris Werbung - Folienshop Bonn_files/twitter.gif" alt="Twitter" <="" a="">
                        </a></li><a href="">
                        </a><li><a href="">
                            </a><a href="">
                                <img class="img-responsive inline-block socialmedia" src="./Machimaris Werbung - Folienshop Bonn_files/gplus.gif" alt="Google Plus" <="" a="">
                        </a></li><a href="">
                        </a><li><a href="">
                            </a><a href="">
                                <img class="img-responsive inline-block socialmedia" src="./Machimaris Werbung - Folienshop Bonn_files/linked.gif" alt="Facebook" <="" a="">
                        </a></li><a href="">
                        </a><li><a href="">
                            </a><a href="">
                                <img class="img-responsive inline-block socialmedia" src="./Machimaris Werbung - Folienshop Bonn_files/youtube.gif" alt="Facebook" <="" a="">
                        </a></li><a href="">
                        </a><li><a href="">
                            </a><a href="">
                                <img class="img-responsive inline-block socialmedia" src="./Machimaris Werbung - Folienshop Bonn_files/vimeo.gif" alt="Facebook" <="" a="">
                        </a></li><a href="">
                    </a></ul><a href="">
                </a></div><a href="">
            </a></div><a href="">
            <!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </a></div><a href="">
    </a></nav><a href="">
```

It seems like its putting `<a>` tags everywhere and transform my code into weird markup :D

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="http://getbootstrap.com/favicon.ico">

    <title></title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--Custom Fonts for this Project -->
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab:400,700,300,100' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <!-- Just for debugging purposes. Don't actually copy these 2 lines! -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="../../assets/js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <script src="Starter%20Template%20for%20Bootstrap-Dateien/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js"></script>

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar navbar-static killmarginbottom" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <ul class="list-inline text-center">
                    <li>
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
                            <img class="" src="img/machimarislogo2.gif" alt="Machima">
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                    <h4>MENU</h4>
                </button>

            </div>
            <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <div class="row">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right margin-top40">
                        <li class="navfrankone active"><a href="index.html">Startseite</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="navfrankone"><a href="referenz.html">Referenzen</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="navfrankone"><a href="anfrage.html">Anfrage</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
               </div>
            <!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div>
    </nav>
  
    <!-- This line is where the <a> tag appears -->
  
    <div class="container margin-bottom20">
        <h2 class="text-center">GET IN TOUCH</h2>
        <p class="text-center">Nutzen Sie die Möglichkeit und kontaktieren Sie uns.</p>
```

Comment: It is not valid to have an `<h4>` element inside a `<button>` element. This is probably messing things up.

Comment: Maybe a referenced script is creating the tag?

Comment: Where this `a` tag links to? Maybe some virus on your PC?

Comment: @Volvox its just an empty a tag which provides the unwanted function of being clickable.

Comment: @luke2012 I've tried to comment every referencescript out. But still the <a> tag magical appears.

Comment: I think your html is invalid and your browser is desperately trying to fix it. Try to validate your code on the w3c site. http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: I believe I run in to this in the past...I think... it could be that you forget to close an <a> tag some where, so double check your code.